# How do I get text UI to appear when a condition in another script is met?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

this is my first question so I don't know much about 'question etiquette' as it were. I'm working in C# in Unity, with Visual Studio.

I'm a little stuck trying to get text to appear when another script has a condition met.

A script (let's call it ManagerScript) attached to an empty (let's call it Manager) that manages some enemies that get destroyed counts the amount of enemies that are destroyed, and once that number hits 8, I want text to appear that tells the user they win.

How can I do this? I have some text UI (let's call the object WinnerText) on a Canvas Panel, but I don't know how to make it 'active' only once the player wins.

Please don't just give me the answer - please explain the reasoning as well if you can, so I can do the same thing for when the player loses the game.

Thanks in advance!
Golden Viper

Comment: Everytime you destroy an enemy -> add points -> in this moment check `if(points > neededPoints)` and then `theUI.SetActive(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Your ManagerScript that keeps track of counting should check for your winning/losing condition after it was modified, like:

```
number++;
if(number > x)
{
// Display Text
}
```

To display your text or other ui element. You need some kind of reference to the gameobject or the component directly. Since the ManagerScript does not know about it, you need to give it a reference to the Component/GameObject you want to activate/deactivate.

Unity offers multiple ways of getting your reference. For example you can declare within your ManagerScript a `public GameObject MyUiElement` (instead of gameobject you can also just have the component you need f.e. 'Text'). If you declared a public Property, a new area within the inspector of your 'Manager' will appear where you can reference your Object by drag & drop or simply by clicking and sleecting.

Other ways of getting the desired gameobjects reference would be with GameObject.Find or similar. For more information about find see: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

If you got your GameObjects reference you can manipulate it like

```
number++;
if(number > x)
{
  MyUiElement.SetActive(true/false);
}
```